# Insert into statement with two max clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `t_process_version` and `t_process_step`

t_process_version

```
id | process_id
```

t_process_step

```
id | version_id | other_thing
```

I'm trying to insert a new process step for every existing version of a process. I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO t_process_step(id, process_vn_id, other_thing)
SELECT (SELECT MAX(ps1.id) + 1 FROM t_process_step ps1),
cpv.id, 
'Other stuff' 
FROM t_process_step ps, t_process_version pv
WHERE ps.version_id = cpv.id
AND pv.process_id = 'some process'
GROUP BY cpv.id
```

This doesn't work because the max(ps1.id) clause is only evaluated once and therefore a primary key error is thrown. From reading around I think this can be resolved using the `over` clause but I'm a bit befuddle by what I've read.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to do this, you could use `row_number()`:

```
INSERT INTO t_process_step(id, process_vn_id, other_thing)
    SELECT (SELECT MAX(ps1.id)  FROM t_process_step ps1) +
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
          cpv.id, 
          'Other stuff' 
    FROM t_calc_process ps JOIN
         t_process_version pv
         ON ps.version_id = cpv.id
    WHERE pv.process_id = 'some process'
    GROUP BY cpv.id;
```

I strongly do not recommend doing this.  Usually an `IDENTITY` column is the right solution for a unique integer id in a table.

Comment: Absolutely agree - I'm stuck with this data model due to reasons outwith my control though so thanks very much for the help